# How can I create a C module with a "static" object of a custom type?

Tags: python, python-c-api

Let's say I want to write a module called `countries` that contains information about the countries of the world. I want to write it in C. It will expose a member called `countries` which is a list of objects of type `Country`. The `Country` type has two members: `name` and `capital`, both strings. So we could do something like this:

```
>>> from countries import countries
>>> countries[0].name
Afghanistan
>>> countries[0].capital
Kabul
```

Following the various scraps of tutorials I was able to find online, I figured out how to create my custom `Country` type in C. It looks basically like this:

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    char *name;
    char *capital;
} Country;

static struct PyMemberDef CountryMembers[] = {
    {"name", T_OBJECT_EX, offsetof(Country, name), 0, "name"},
    {"capital", T_OBJECT_EX, offsetof(Country, capital), 0, "capital"},
    {NULL}
};

static PyTypeObject CountryType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    .tp_name = "countries.Country",
    .tp_doc = "Country",
    .tp_basicsize = sizeof(Country),
    .tp_itemsize = 0,
    .tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,
    .tp_new = PyType_GenericNew,
    .tp_members = CountryMembers
};
```

and then in the module init function, call `Py_TypeReady` and add the type to the module. However, what I cannot figure out how to do is create a new instance of this type, in C, add it to the module, *and populate its fields*. The closest I can get is this, again in the module init function:

```c
PyObject *afghanistan = PyObject_CallObject((PyObject*) &CountryType, NULL);
PyModule_AddObject(local_module, "afghanistan", (PyObject*) afghanistan);
```

But I don't know how to fill in the members.

Comment: `T_OBJECT_EX` and `char *` don't match. Either `T_OBJECT_EX` should be `T_STRING`, or `char *` should be `PyObject *`, depending on how you actually want these objects to work.

Comment: You really ought to write a meaningful constructor, too.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Do I have to? That feels like it should be unnecessary, considering I just want to populate these things with fixed values. I don't intend for  anyone to construct objects of type `Country` from Python.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to cast the `PyObject*` to a `Country*` and then you can set the members yourself:

```
Country *afghanistan = (Country*)PyObject_CallObject((PyObject*) &CountryType, NULL);
afghanistan->name = "Afghanistan";
afghanistan->captial = "Kabul";
PyModule_AddObject(local_module, "afghanistan", (PyObject*) afghanistan);
```

Obviously if you want `name` and `capital` to point to non-static strings then you need to `malloc` them and `free` them appropriately in the constructor.

---

Given that it sounds like you don't want this class to be constructable from Python then you might to properly ban that with [`Py_TPFLAGS_DISALLOW_INSTANTIATION`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#Py_TPFLAGS_DISALLOW_INSTANTIATION) (on older versions of Python just set `tp_new` to `NULL`). You'd then create a C-only "constructor" function:

```
static Country* MakeCountry(const char* name, const char* capital) {
   Country *c = CountryType.tp_alloc(&CountryType, 0);
   c->name = name;
   c->capital = capital;
   return c;
}
```

And use that function instead of `PyObject_CallObject((PyObject*)&CountryType, NULL)`.